# Adding buttons to a frame using GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am doing an assignment I'm a little stuck on. I have these requirements:

- 1 frame with BorderLayout
- 2 buttons on Panel
- 1 Panel with GridLayout to put the two buttons on in the SOUTH region
- 1 FileChooser in a new frame
- 1 TextArea in the CENTRAL region
- 1 Label telling what the program does in the NORTH region

I will be taking the input from two files from my temp folder and reading them into
the text field in the middle of the screen.

I can't figure out why both buttons won't show up.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class P_Supplemental_11 extends JFrame {

JPanel jpnl1 = new JPanel();
JButton jbtReadFile1 = new JButton("Get Student Names");
JButton jbtReadFile2 = new JButton("Get Student Grades");
JTextField jtxtFilePath = new JTextField();
JLabel jlblDesc = new JLabel("Enter the file name here:");
JTextArea jtxtAfileContents = new JTextArea();

P_Supplemental_11() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 10));
    jpnl1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    jpnl1.add(jlblDesc);
    jpnl1.add(jtxtFilePath);
    add(jpnl1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(jtxtAfileContents, BorderLayout.CENTER);



    add(jbtReadFile1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    jbtReadFile1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

         jbtReadFileActionPerformed(evt);
     }

    });

    add(jbtReadFile2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    jbtReadFile2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

         jbtReadFileActionPerformed2(evt);
     }

    });
  } // end constructor


 private void jbtReadFileActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        File inFile = new File("c:/temp/studentnames.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
        String fileContents = "";
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            fileContents+= input.nextLine() + "\n";
        } // end while

        jtxtAfileContents.setText(fileContents);
        input.close();




    } // end action method for jbtReadFile button
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(P_Supplemental_11.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,            ex);
    }
}

private void jbtReadFileActionPerformed2(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        File inFile = new File("c:/temp/studentscores.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);
        String fileContents = "";
        while(input.hasNext()) {
            fileContents+= input.nextLine() + "\n";
        } // end while
        input.close();
        jtxtAfileContents.setText(fileContents);





    } // end action method for jbtReadFile button
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(P_Supplemental_11.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,    
 ex);
    }
}


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    P_Supplemental_11 frame = new P_Supplemental_11();
    frame.setTitle("P_Supplemenetal_10");
    frame.setSize(410, 520);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a panel with a `GridLayout` in the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` location as specified in the assignment.

2 buttons cannot share the same location in a `BorderLayout` with *both* being visible at the same time:

```
add(jbtReadFile1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

add(jbtReadFile2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: So, how would I put them next to each other on the south part of the frame? The assignment only calls to use one frame

Comment: Then do I need to take out my section add(jbtReadFile1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        jbtReadFile1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            
             jbtReadFileActionPerformed(evt);
         }

Comment: Just amend the `add` call based on the instructions in the assignment.

Comment: Great that worked! Thanks! One last question - for the second file I'm inputting - it has 2 columns of data (an ID field and a grades field) - I need to output the student id, grades and average grade in the text area ... How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Not clear on the format of the file. How exactly is average calculated? -> what is output format of grades?